# AWS::ApiGateway::Stage requires DeploymentId ... but where do I find this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to programmatically set up stages as part of my AWS API Gateway deployment. I am using SAM CLI. [The cloudformation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-stage.html) give the definition:

> DeploymentId The ID of the deployment that the stage points to.
>
> Required: Yes
>
> Type: String
>
> Update requires: No interruption

and the code example:

```yaml
Resources:
  Prod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Description: Prod Stage
      RestApiId: !Ref MyRestApi
      DeploymentId: !Ref TestDeployment ##      <===== this
      DocumentationVersion: !Ref MyDocumentationVersion
      ClientCertificateId: !Ref ClientCertificate
      Variables:
        Stack: Prod
      MethodSettings:
        - ResourcePath: /
          HttpMethod: GET
          MetricsEnabled: 'true'
          DataTraceEnabled: 'true'
        - ResourcePath: /stack
          HttpMethod: POST
          MetricsEnabled: 'true'
          DataTraceEnabled: 'true'
          ThrottlingBurstLimit: '999'
        - ResourcePath: /stack
          HttpMethod: GET
          MetricsEnabled: 'true'
          DataTraceEnabled: 'true'
          ThrottlingBurstLimit: '555'
```

..but no context as to what the value `TestDeployment` points to.

- Is it a random string the user selects?
- Is it a generated ID that is available somewhere?
- Is it the name of a Resource or API? etc.

I have been googling and still can't seem to get an answer.

Looking in the AWS management console, I can see looking at some of our already existing APIs - that when stages *already exist* (manually set up) you can get a deployment ID via the stages, but if I have to manually set them up first, that would kind of partially defeat the purpose of CloudFormation's `AWS::ApiGateway::Stage` wouldn't it (...ideally, we hope to be able to create API's *completely* via code, without going into the AWS interface)? And wouldn't the `deploymentId` only be available after the deployment? If it's available prior (as part of the build), how do I fetch it and get it into my `cloudformation.yaml` prior to a deploy?

Any help in understanding this is appreciated!

Comment: The documentation [linked above](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-stage.html) now seems to indicate DeploymentId is not required: `DeploymentId Required: No`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Deployment contains metadata about an API Gateway deploy, such as a description, and can also be used to deploy a [canary release](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/canary-release.html). You can create a [Deployment resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-deployment.html) as part of your CloudFormation template.

```
Deployment: 
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
  Properties: 
    RestApiId: 
      Ref: "MyApi"
    Description: "My deployment"
    StageName: "DummyStage"
```

When you `!Ref` it it will return the `DeploymentId`. Make sure to read the section of the docs called *AWS::ApiGateway::Method Dependency* to learn how to attach API methods to the deployment.

Comment: Thank you so much! The AWS docs are... not always (by always I mean usually) clear. Quick pile-on question if you don't mind... If I wanted to create multiple stages (labs/dev/prod), can that be done in the same template?

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. I haven't defined multiple stages in a template before, but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work. Unless there's a good reason not to, consider managing the dev/qa versions of the API from separate AWS accounts that manage those environments entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Simple explanation:

1. go to the API
2. click DEPLOY
3. somewhat bizarrely, **you have to select "NO STAGE"**

It gives you strange and confusing warnings when you do this. Ignore the warnings.

4. Deploy it with "NO STAGE"

***Only then can you create your first stage!***

It's just one of those whacky AWS things. Next you now CAN create one or more stages. Create a stage, and then put the API on that stage, rather than on "NO STAGE"

Summary - bizarrely you have to deploy an API to "NO STAGE" before you're allowed to make a stage!